# iron-data-table accessibility options

Tags: html, polymer, accessibility

I cannot seem to access my `iron-data-table` via tabbing, considering that I am trying to create an accessible web interface.

Does anybody have any knowledge of such things?

Setting `tabindex="0"` on the `iron-data-table` itself does enable the generic data table to be selected, but I cannot find a way to tab through the entries themselves...

```
<iron-data-table tabindex="0" aria-label="Server properties list" items="{{uksproperties}}">
    <!-- Styling for the iron-data-table is imported via bower_components/iron-data-table/default-styles.html in bower-imports.html -->
    <data-table-column name="Key" sort-by="key">
        <template>{{item.key}}</template>
    </data-table-column>
    <data-table-column name="Value" sort-by="value">
        <template>{{item.value}}</template>
    </data-table-column>
    <data-table-column name="Server" sort-by="server">
        <template is="header">
             <span class="flex">Server</span>
             <paper-button aira-label="export server properties list" class="download" raised>
                <iron-icon icon="launch"></iron-icon>
                Export
             </paper-button>
        </template>
        <template>{{item.server}}</template>
    </data-table-column>
</iron-data-table>
```

Comment: So you mean you want to tab through each and every cell of `iron-datatable`?

Comment: @Ofisora: Something like that, yeah. I can't figure out quite how to get to tab into the elements on it. I'd probably say that being able to tab each row would be good. Every cell may be a stretch, but it could be useful to know.

Comment: Why are you using `iron-datatable`, it is no longer active. I suggest you to use `vaadin-grid`: https://vaadin.com/elements/-/element/vaadin-grid.

Comment: It's just what I found at the time. I will check out Vaadin and get back to you.